# How can I correct the wrong icon for a website bookmark?

Tags: safari, catalina, icon, bookmarks

In Safari, the icon of Reddit is displayed as the icon of StackOverflow. How can I correct it? Things I have already tried are:

- Deleting the bookmark, and re-adding it
- Using `Command+R` to refresh the website (reddit)

Software Environment:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.1
- Safari 13.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Hold shift while starting up Safari from the dock.

Go to Develop menu and do Empty Caches. If Develop Menu is not there, enable it in Safari Settings under Advanced tab.

One can also dig in Caches folder in ~/Library and find the icons there.